# Firebase Pods Constantly Releasing New Versions/Changing Source

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm working on an Xcode project in Swift that relies on Firebase, which I downloaded through Cocoapods. Since the start of 2020, a variety of errors related to Pods will appear every 4 days or so and crash the build. Running pod install and pod update fixes the issues, however, in another 4 days or so new errors are back. The most recent errors are Swift compiler errors that read `Duplicate interface definition for class 'FIRApp'` or `Redefinition of 'FIRLoggerLevel'` for a number of different files of the type "Firebase.h"
When running pod update I'll usually receive a long list of pods that have been updated or whose source has changed:

```
Installing Firebase 6.21.0 (was 6.20.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 6.4.0 (was 6.3.1 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FirebaseAuth 6.5.1 (was 6.5.0 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FirebaseCore 6.6.5 (was 6.6.4 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FirebaseInstallations 1.1.1 (was 1.1.0 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement 6.4.0 (was 6.3.1 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing GoogleDataTransport 5.1.0 (was 5.0.0 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport 2.0.1 (was 2.0.0 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
```

Does anyone know why the pods are updating and changing sources so often since the start of 2020? This issue makes it impossible to develop efficiently because I'm constantly running into these errors and recently running pod install and pod update has not fixed the errors. Any suggestions, explanations, or other comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase does regular incremental improvement releases. See details in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).

If you'd like to avoid updating use `pod install` instead of `pod update`. `pod install` keeps the previously installed versions specified in `Podfile.lock`. `pod update` will update to the latest installed versions.

Comment: Okay, but if I don't run pod install and pod update regularly I open my project to find a number of Cocoapods/Firebase related errors even though I haven't changed any of the code that was running fine a day or two ago. How do I get around that?

Comment: If nothing is changing, it should still run the same way.  That's probably a separate question to isolate what exactly is changing and why it's causing a breakage.